# Center one <div> and float other right

Tags: html, css

I want div "1" to the center and div "2" to the right. what can i do? I have this html

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="1"></div>
  <div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.1 {
display:inline-block; 
width:200px; 
height:120px;}
.2 {
display:inline-block; 
width:250px; 
height:120px;
float:right;}
```

Comment: Looking at the website you have linked to in comments below, your HTML is broken in places. For example you have `</tr>` tags with no co-responding opening tags. Run your page through an HTML validator and fix the obvious errors. Better still get rid of tables for lay out purposes.

Comment: Man I know that issues but I need to fix the header one

Comment: Broken HTML **may** be your issue. When you have random unmatched tags, the results may will be random. With valid, or at least, not broken, HTML, the answer from @index should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

First I know it's just sample but don't use number for first character for classes ([Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)).

And this is what I usually use to do that

```
<div id="block">
    <div id="right">Right</div>
    <div id="middle">Middle</div>
</div>

#middle {
    background-color: #494949;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#right {
    background-color: #949494;
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/index/npq5puc1/.

Comment: Do you have to specify display:block for  a block element?

Comment: A. No. I think that was just left there from copying the css of the question. *cleared*

Comment: no worries (just typing some more to reach the character threshold)

Comment: Could you check the fiddle and see if that's the one you're trying to achieve? If not, maybe you can do a small screenshot?

Comment: The website I'm working is http://www.gioccocraft.com/index.php tell me about it

Comment: yeah is that I'm trying but if you can see the website gioccocraft.com/index.php ... it doesn't work

Comment: Okay. Walk me through this, w/c is suppose to be in the middle and the one on the right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1.) Change HTML element according to CSS to get desire result

```css
.div1 {
display:inline-block; 
width:200px; 
height:120px;
  background:red;
  float:right;

}
.div2 {
display:inline-block; 
width:250px; 
height:120px;
float:right;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="div2">div 2 in right</div>
  <div class="div1">div 1 in center</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this;

html

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.div1 
{
    display:block;
    background:#333;
    width:200px; 
    height:120px;
    margin:auto;
}
.div2 
{
    display:block; 
    background:red;
    width:250px; 
    height:120px;
    float:right;
}
```

Here's the Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Laky/gymL7jdh/).

Comment: it doesn't work yet :S I don't know why

Comment: Yeah, I can't see anything wrong but the fiddle doesn't work. (Display on one line, that is)

Comment: @DylanB you mean even in fiddle it shows up in one line?

Comment: The website I'm working is http://www.gioccocraft.com/index.php tell me about it

Comment: The fiddle puts the divs on separate lines. @kennyamaro that website has a few issues which I'm sure you'll fix but for the love of good UX please get a smaller image of Pear Earrings, that's a 2mb file and watching it load is painful.

Comment: this errors are things I have  to fix but I'm talking about the header and how to align those elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this
HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="1"></div>
  <div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
[class='1'] {
display:inline-block; 
width:200px; 
height:120px;}
[class='2'] {
display:inline-block; 
width:250px; 
height:120px;
float:right;}
```